# Is there a simpler way of calling JSON in a Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2

I managed to call in a JSON file into my router and access the content in the template. However, I'm wondering if there's a simpler way of calling my data. Is there a way to just call `{{ title }}` for example, and not `{{ data["title"] }}`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**router_article_02.py**

```py
@app.route('/article-02/welcome')
    def article_02_welcome():
        with app.open_resource("templates/article-02/data.json", "r" ) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)

    return render_template("article-02/welcome.html", data = data)
```

**article-02.html**

```html
<h1>{{ data["title"] }}</h1>
<div class="overline">Category: {{ data["category-type"] }}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I needed to unpack the dictionary using the double asterisks or dictionary unpacking operator (`**`) notation.

**router_article_02.py**

```py
@app.route('/article-02/welcome')
def article_02_welcome():
    with app.open_resource("templates/article-02/data.json", "r" ) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    return render_template("article-02/welcome.html", **data)
```

**article-02.html**

```html
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<div class="overline">Category: {{ category_type }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `key` is a valid python variable name the you can also use the dot `.` notation.

```
data = {
    'name': 'My Name',
    'current employer': 'Google',
    'country-name': 'USA',
    'state_name': 'CA'
}
```

Then 
`{{data.name}}` and `{{data.state_name}}` will work, but for the rest you have to use the bracket syntax:
`{{data['country-name']}}` and `{{data['current employer']}}`.

Documentation

- [Variables in Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#variables)